# Download files interrupted in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have trouble with downloading files in my server.
Server information :

```
- EC2 of AWS
- Rails : 5.1.4
- Rbenv : 1.1.1
- Ruby : 2.4.3
```

Expected cases :

- Download file with size 1.2GB from EC2 server.

Problem :

- File download gets interrupted randomly, For the first time I almost downloaded 1 GB and then it failed, now it fails anywhere (50MB or 100MB or 300MB, etc)

It only occurs in ec2 server, works fine in my local system

I tried setting `proxy_max_temp_file_size` in nginx but it did not help.

Any help or explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to download file by putting it into background?

Comment: @Abhinay No, i downloading file through url.
I trying to using scp command to copy file from ssh into my local machine.